# How does Market cap and daily movement affect a Crypto stock , do these numbers mean much?

Tags: mining-reward, currencies, marketplace

Really want to understand how the daily volume and overall cap works. I read that don't buy when a market cap is over 75 million and the best time to buy is between 25 and 75 million.
I understand that certain coins have mineable limits. Do some coins have unlimited caps ? How would they be valuable and not subject to inflation ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To clarify the definitions for you:

Market cap => The total money invested into a coin (or stock). This is the sum of peoples perceived value of the coin and the amount of coins i.e. MK = Coin Value * No. of coins in supply. To answer your question, coins do not have limits on market caps (in other words the perceived value of the coin is unlimited).

Mineable limits => This is probably referring to A. The automatic mining difficulty adjustment of a coin and B. the hard limit on supply of the coins. Both of these are to prevent inflation of the coin. Inflation occurs on coins while they are mineable but usually small and steady and usually decreasing inflation (like Bitcoins block halving).

With regards to trading/investing, it may be wiser to analyse the market cap of the coin rather than the coin value. If you believe it is a worthy idea to invest in then for you to make a good return you would require a balance of 1. Small enough market cap that has potential to multiply 2. Coin supply is regulated by mining to prevent runaway inflation (premined can be risky) 3. The hard limit on the coin is reasonable. Just remember that the coins with the biggest market caps may be considered more trusted/reliable.